# subclipse install instructions for eclipse neon 4.6.1 and svn server 1.7 on windows

Tags: svn, subclipse

I have been searching the web for a while and it is not clear exactly what I need to install to get subclipse 1.8 working on windows eclipse neon 4.6.1 communicating with svn server 1.7 where tortoise svn is already installed on the windows client.

In the subclipse wiki:

https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki

there is a link to an older version of subclipse which I think I am supposed to install for svn server 1.7 compatibility:

https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/archive/release/1.8.x/

However, it seems strange that the latest version would not be backward compatible and be able to understand what version of svn the server is.  Also, I would like to install it from a zip file and the policies of my employer will not allow end users to install things form the internet, so utilizing eclipse market place will likly not be an option and I cannot find any instructions that do not involve eclipse market place?

Also, I understand I need an "svn client / connector", is tortoise svn sufficient?  Do I need SilkSVN or a different connector in addition to tortoise svn?  Tortoise svn is already packaged and functional as the correct client version compatible with svn server 1.7, so if I could just use the tortoise svn connector that would be perfiect?  If not, Would I need to uninstall tortoise SVN before installing a windows connector that subclipse is expecting?

My employer has not given me admin rights to any of these boxes and I don't have a personal svn 1.7 server stood up to test against.  I suppose it is kind of a shot in the dark that there would be instructions for such a specific environment, but I am really hoping that someone can point me in the right direction or provide instructions that I can pass along to the packaging team at my employer for them to try?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The version of your server is not relevant, it could be 1.0, it could be 1.9.  So you should use the newest version of Subclipse.  Where the version is relevant is in coexisting with other SVN clients on the same computer.  For example, if you are using TortoiseSVN with SVN 1.9.x client libraries then you want to use the same for Subclipse.  Since you are obviously on Windows, the Subclipse install for Windows includes everything you need.  It does not use TortoiseSVN though.

There is a link to download zipped update site on the wiki page you mentioned:

https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/

You should get the latest version which is 4.2.1.